# Is there random variation in post-evolution CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

Say my friend and I are both level 20, with identical XP, and we simultaneously catch an identical 500CP Pokemon. If we then both evolve this Pokemon, will it always have the same post-evolution XP?

Additionally, what other factors would influence variation in post evolution CP?

Would a size/height disparity result in different post evolution HP? (I've seen some discussion on this but no definitive answer).

How about if my friend evolved immediately, but I waited until I was level 21?

Do all Pokemon of the same species increase in post-evolution CP at a similar rate? If so, how does this rate vary across different species?

Comment: if one becomes extra small/large then it may not have the same cp

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273865/pok%C3%A9mon-go-evolution?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The CP post-evolution will always stay at the same percentage of the max possible CP at your current trainer level. You can see this in the semi-circle behind the Pokemon. It will always stay just as filled after evolution as it was before.

Due to how weight and height (supposedly) affect Max CP, two Pokemon of the same species may not have the same maximum CP. As a result, they may not gain the same amount of CP post-evolution.

If your friend evolved now and you waited until Level 21, your Pokemon will gain more CP as your CP cap is (supposedly) higher than your friend's currently is.

Comment: supposedly? - .

Comment: @Aequitas We still don't have definitive information as to how much (if at all) weight and height affects CP.